# How to redirect url after form submit in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

The problem is to redirect URL for submit button in Codeigniter. I want to fetch data from the database by submitting a query in the form and can't do it as there is a redirection problem.

this is a xampp server.

WELCOMe

```
        <!-- <form action="submit.php" > -->
          <form action="submit.php" id="#form" name="#form" >


      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="s_id">Student ID:</label>
            <input type="int" class="form-control" id="s_id" placeholder="Student ID" name="s_id"  >
            </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="s_name">Student Name:</label>
            <input type="int" class="form-control" id="s_name" placeholder="Student Name" name="s_name"  >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="training">Training:</label>
            <input type="int" class="form-control" id="training" placeholder="Training" name="training"  >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
            <input type="int" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" name="phone"  >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
          <!--  <input type="submit" calss="form-control btn btn-success" value="Search" name="submitbtn">  -->
            <input id='btn' name="submitbtn" type='submit' value='Submit'>
          </div>
        </div>


    </form>
```

Expected: I want to fetch data from the database by submitting a query in the form and can't do it as there is a redirection problem.

Actual:

> 404 Page Not Found
>   The page you requested was not found.

Comment: Can you show us the PHP code who is call by the submit ?

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a redirection problem. It just says 404 Not Found. Is it saying that for `submit.php`? Or is it redirecting to a different URL which is not found? Why do you think `submit.php` or the other URL should exist?

Comment: Is `Submit.php` a CodeIgniter "controller" ? If so, is there an `index()` method for the controller and is `index()` intended to handle the submit data? Instead of the view's code, it would be better to show the parts of `Submit.php` you expect to handle data from the form.

Comment: <?php
//echo 'hello';


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
// Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
$id = $_POST['s_id'];
$name = $_POST['s_name'];
$training = $_POST['training'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
if($id !=''&& $name !=''&& $training !=''&& $phone !='')
{
//  To redirect form on a particular page
header("Location:https://www.formget.com/app/");
}
else{
?><span><?php echo "Please fill all fields.....!!!!!!!!!!!!";?></span> <?php
}
}
?>

Comment: @Fizik26 here is the code of submit.php

Comment: @DFriend no it is in view but I don't know where to keep it

Comment: @MohitSanwal Please do not add lots of code in comments. You should edit the question and add the code there instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use AJAX

```
<script>
function submitForms(){
//getting values from your form
formData = $("#Form").serialize();
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>super/user/add",
data:formData ,

success:function(data) {
//response
}

}
});
 event.preventDefault();
};
</script>`
```

In your form

```
 <form method="post" id="Form" name="Form" action="javascript:submitForms();">
```

Comment: can I do it using simple codes ie; without using AZAX?